# How to let the user select type in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I would like to make a sorting application that lets the user pick the length of the array to be sorted and the type of element that randomly populates the array. For example if the user picks 3 as the length and String as the type, the array could look like this:

```
{‘ababa’, ‘abcd’, ‘fgh’ }
```

To sort an array of any type, I have created an abstract class that looks like this:

```
abstract public class Sort<T extends Comparable<T>> {

protected T[] array;

public boolean isLessThan(T obj1, T obj2) {
    if (obj1.compareTo(obj2) < 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public String toString() {
    String result = "";
    boolean first = true;
    for (T each : array) {
        if (first == true) {
            result += each.toString();
            first = false;
        } else {
            result += ", "+each.toString();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

abstract public void sort(T[] array);
}
```

And an example sorting algorithm that looks like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class Bogo<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Sort<T> {

public T[] shuffle(T[] array) { //taken from www.journaldev.com/32661/shuffle-array-java
    List<T> list = Arrays.asList(array);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return list.toArray(array);
}


public boolean isSorted(T[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (isLessThan(array[i+1], array[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public void sort(T[] array) {
    //if array is Sorted return array
    while (true) { //not needed for recursive method
        if (isSorted(array)) {
            super.array = array; //super.array same as this.array?
            break;
        } else { //otherwise shuffle array randomly
            super.array = shuffle(array);
        }
    }
    
}

}
```

At this point I can call bogo.sort(array) with an array of any type and get the correct answer. But the problem is I have to declare the variable array.

I can declare it as

```
Integer[] array = {1,3,2,3,4};
```

or

```
String[] array = {‘ababa’, ‘abcd’, ‘fgh’ };
```

But if I try to say

```
if user input is 1 
then declare as Integer[] 
else declare as String[]
```

then I get:

```
array cannot be resolved to a variable
```

on

```
bogo.sort(array);
```

I tried making a separate class GenericArray that has a T array as a variable, but then I get:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to T
```

on

```
array[i] = rand.nextInt();
```

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: I don't understand what problem you are trying to solve. If there exists data to sort already, then it's stored in an array with a particular type, yeah?

Comment: Just to make sure... you do know bogosort is a joke, right? The point of it is that it's terrible and people make fun of it.

Comment: Considering the sort you are doing I guess efficiency isn't the goal.  But to shuffle an object array all you have to do is `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array))` since the array backs up the list.  Note that it won't work for primitive arrays.

Comment: You can't. Java is a statically typed language.

Comment: If you really must do it this way then consider using an `Object` array like so `Object[] array = new Object[]{"abcd",20};`, then it doesn't matter what type of data you want to store in it. Just be careful that when sorting or getting the data that you check if it is a valid instance of string or int and type cast as needed.